# Auto fix TSLint warning in IntelliJ and WebStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Is there any way to fix the TSLint warning automatically in IntelliJ and WebStorm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes: hit `Alt-Enter` on the highlighted problem and select either **TSLint: fix current problem** to fix only this particular issue or **TSLint: fix current file** to apply the fixes when possible to the whole file.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/webstorm-2017-1-eap-171-2455/ for more info

Comment: and what do you want?

Comment: can it be configured to do atuomatically

Comment: to run fixes automatically? No. We will hardly ever add features supposed to modify the code silently, without user action

Comment: oh ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: I would like to do this in the save-action plugin :)

Comment: @lena I love that as a core assumption. However, it's a very nice feature of ts/eslint and having the ability to configure it to auto-fix explicitly (defaulting to not) would be very nice.

Comment: @lena I hit Alt + Enter and the pop up menu doesn't  have "fix current file" or "fix current error". Webstorm 2018.2.5. Maybe this is a bug of new Webstorm? please help,

Comment: @V.Tran Shift-Shift and type "Fix current file".  That should find and run the tslint command

Comment: Ashish, you don't want 100% continuous automatic "fixing" lint warnings, because there will be cases where you won't be able to type the desired code - because it can't pass Lint until after everything is typed in - so it would be undoing your work as you type! However, @lena I'd like to explicitly, manually turn on auto-fixing at particular intervals, like upon running, manual saving, committing... hell, maybe even upon the editor losing focus (tab/window switching). Each time it happens, give a bottom-right event pop-up with a link to the diff of what changed, in case one cares to look.